# derivative with using chain rule

Tags: derivatives

Let $H(x) = h(h(x)h(x^2))$ be.

Is it something like this $h'(h(x)h(x^2))(h(x)h(x^2))'?$

what is a derivative of this function?

Comment: $\color{red}{(h(x)h(x^2))'h'(h(x)h(x^2))}=(h'(x)h(x^2)+2xh'(x^2)h(x))h'(h(x)h(x^2))$

Comment: thank you! it means that you also used product rule, right?

Comment: yes, you are right